# How to unroot an AOSP Nexus build?

Tags: android, android-source

When building AOSP from source for any of the nexus devices, the only `BUILDTYPE` (build configuration) that is compatible with any of the nexus devices, (as listed here: https://source.android.com/source/running.html), is `userdebug`, but which is:

> like "user" but with root access and debuggability;
>   preferred for debugging

There doesn't seem to be any other option listed in the table on this page: https://source.android.com/source/running.html

So how do we revoke "root" ? Or is there a way to build without "root" perhaps like "user" instead ?

I also noticed, that when USB debugging is enabled, it doesn't matter what the key / hash of the computer the android device is connected to is - it doesn't check the keys anymore. Anyway to change that as well ?

EDIT: If I set the build configuration to "user" instead of "user-debug", then apparently it is not root, but the problem is that usb-debugging is then disabled. How can I prevent root access, but keep debuggability ?

Answer (score -3):

A "user" build *is* how you make a non-"rooted" AOSP build, hence the surviving part of your question is the edit asking why ADB is not enabled there.

The answer to that is that with an AOSP "user" build you have (a subset of) a typical end-user Android device where both ADB and the Developer menu in settings are off by default in out-of-the-box condition.

As existing questions and answers here will show, to turn on the Developer menu you have to go to the information menu and tap the build number a number of times.  Then you will have a developer menu in which you can enable ADB.

Additionally, with a "user" build of a modern Android version, you will need an ADB client which supports security certificates, and to accept the ADB client's certificate on the Android device.

Comment: it seems that with "user" adb isn't authorised, even when usb debugging is enabled.